# Adding Footer To Card

Tags: html, css

I have hoverable cards that have a nice drop shadow. I am not using bootstrap4 card styles for this.

Here is the card style:

```css
.feature-card {
  box-shadow: 0 13px 34px 0 rgba(75, 111, 255, 0.09);
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 4rem 1.5rem 3rem 1.5rem;
  min-height: 26rem;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow ease 0.3s;
  -o-transition: box-shadow ease 0.3s;
  transition: box-shadow ease 0.3s;
}
.feature-card:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 35px 10px rgba(75, 111, 255, 0.09);
}
.feature-card h3 {
  color: #32404E;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.feature-card p {
  color: #878baa;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2.3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <a href="#" class="feature-card">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Desc/</p>
      <span style="color:#4a8bfc;" class="bolder">Last Line</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And what I am trying to do is add a footer to this card. I want it to be 100% width and I can't seem to make that happen... I am probably missing something very easy but it is escaping me.

I have tried:

Adding this to the html:

```
  <div class="feature-card-footer">
                    <span href="#">Footer</span>
                </div>
```

With this css:

```
  .feature-card-footer {
    padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
    background-color: #f7f7f9;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.125); 
    min-width:100%;

  }
```

I also tried changing the position. But the footer doesn't go side-to-side and does not sit at the bottom of the card. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make `.feature-card` a flex container.
2. Separate the card `HTML` into `card-body` and `card-footer`
3. Use `margin-top: auto` to push the footer to the bottom
4. Move the card's `padding` to the card body - this means it won't affect the footer
5. Add `box-sizing` rule to the footer - it seems not be included by default by Bootstrap here

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/18q4g4s2/2/)

```css
.feature-card {
  box-shadow: 0 13px 34px 0 rgba(75, 111, 255, 0.09);
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  min-height: 26rem;
  /* add flexbox rules */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow ease 0.3s;
  -o-transition: box-shadow ease 0.3s;
  transition: box-shadow ease 0.3s;
}

.feature-card:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 35px 10px rgba(75, 111, 255, 0.09);
}

.feature-card-body {
  /* move the padding to the card-body */
  padding: 4rem 1.5rem 3rem 1.5rem;
}

.feature-card h3 {
  color: #32404E;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.feature-card p {
  color: #878baa;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2.3rem;
}

.feature-card-footer {
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  background-color: #f7f7f9;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  min-width: 100%;
  /* push footer to bottom */
  margin-top: auto;
  /* ensure width includes padding */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <a href="#" class="feature-card">
        <div class="feature-card-body">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p>Desc/</p>
          <span style="color:#4a8bfc;" class="bolder">Last Line</span>
        </div>
        <div class="feature-card-footer">
          <span href="#">Footer</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```